# Recovery doesn't recover what's in swap file

Tags: swap-file, crash-recovery

I have a file and three swap files, `file.swn`, `file.swo` and `file.swp`. I accidentally recovered using `file.swp` and then made some changes. However, I have some newer changes in `file.swn` which I'd like to recover. But when I try to recover from `file.swn`, the changes aren't there even if I can see them in the binary `file.swn` file.

How can I properly recover such changes? I was looking into manual but haven't found an answer. I can copy the changes manually but they're in a bit random order it seems and I'd like to avoid this unnecessary work if possible.

Comment: how did you try recover from `file.swn`?

Comment: `:e file.swn` and then `:recover` or `vim -r file.swn`